# Jackson custom type info not working

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got classes which use an `@JsonTypeIdResolver` to add a custom type field to the output. This code was working as expected. I've now added an `PropertyFilter` to my mapper object. This is where the `@JsonTypeIdResolver` stopped working. The factory is not being called anymore.

Working code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(outputStream,myObject);
```

Not working code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PropertyFilter myfilter=new SimpleBeanFilter() {
   protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
      return true;
   }
   protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
      return true;
   }
}
FilterProvider filters=new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter",myFilter);
mapper.writer(filter).writeValue(outputStream,myObject);
```

As the filter is just useless (accepts anything) the output should be the same. Why does my type field not get serialized anymore?

Comment: Which version of Jackson?

Comment: Can you share the code of the class you are trying to serialize?

Comment: Just try it with any Pojos you like. I've created a seperate project to proove this failure. Same problem. Even if you use `CLASS` (builtin) type descriptor it's the same issue. EDIT: I found the issue, seems like this has something to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Jackson doesn't deal with inheritance the right way. My test setup was like

```
 @JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "_type" )
 abstract class Base {
     String somefield;
     ...
 }

 class ChildA extends Base {
     ...
 }

 class ChildB extends Base {
     ...
 }
```

If I write a custom serializer, which explicitely casts `ChildA` and `ChildB` to `Base` before serializing, it works as expected. So the basic issue is that jackson does not recognize annotations on parent objects, if not explicitly told to do so.

Comment: Didn't you include `@JsonSubTypes`?